# Products not showing in category page and search result

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, search

The Products that I created, are not showing in selected category pages and not showing the search results. How can I fix this?

## **Products Properties:**

- **Status:** Enabled
- **Visibility:** Catalog, Search
- **Inventory:** Manage Stock: No (that's mean the product in stock)
- **Main Website:** Selected
- **Product Categories:** Selected

## **Categories Properties:**

- **Is Active:** Yes
- **Display Mode:** Products Only
- **Is Anchor:** Yes

Please note that when I entered the URL key in the browser, the product page showing and its available, but the products are just not showing in category page and search result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you cleared the Cache

Comment: Which type of products are these ?

Comment: just do reindexing

Comment: i have a problem when i am trying to do reindex product prices, would anyone please tell me where the code that is responsible for that :)

Comment: What error you got while re indexing. Do you have access to putty.

Comment: For product type _Grouped Product_, at least one of its _Associated Products_ must be enabled and visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to run reindex in **shell** folder.

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

or in admin panel:

System -> Index Management

Comment: Yes correct, but i have a problem when i am trying to reindex product prices, and i have resolve that by delete some rows from the db, thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have noticed that running the indexing in the admin panel does not do the trick, but running in the shell works. Odd.